# Is it grammatically correct to use prepositions as in the example?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct or does it sound natural? If not, how would a native speaker rephrase it?

> This is the sea in which we are going to swim on a holiday we are going to go on next year

Comment: What preposition, exactly?

Comment: on a holiday we are going to go on

Comment: It's OK to do that. If you don't like the repetition of 'on', replace the first 'on' with 'during', or, better still, rewrite the whole thing: This is the sea in which we are going to swim during our holiday next year.

Comment: Even shorter: "This is the sea we are going to swim in during our holiday next year."